# Using save method to extend M2M relationship

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have a model like this

```
class Authority(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country=models.ForeignKey(Country)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category)
    competitors=models.ManyToManyField("self",related_name="competitors")
```

I want authorities having the same country and category and itself to be automatically give an M2M relationship,so i did this

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    z=Authority.objects.filter(country=self.country).filter(category=self.category)
    this_authority=Authority.objects.get(id=self.id)
    for a in z:
        this_authority.competitors.add(a)
    super(Authority,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

It wasn't working and not bringing any error,I also tries this below

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        z=Authority.objects.filter(country=self.country).filter(category=self.category)
        this_authority=Authority.objects.get(id=self.id)
        self.competitors=z
        super(Authority,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

What might be wrong with my code?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Making sure I understand: when you create a new Authority `A`, you want to add `A` to the `competitors` attribute of all existing `Authorities` who have the same `country` and `category` as `A`; and, you want to add all of those `Authorities` to the `competitors` attribute of `A` as well; is that correct?

Comment: @souldeux Yes that's what I want to do.any idea on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working the way you expect is because of how Django handles creating m2m relationships in the database. Long story very short, when you save something like a new `Authority` to the database, Django first writes the new object then goes back in and writes the m2m relationships for that new object. As a result, it's tough to do anything useful to m2m relationships in a custom `save` method.

A [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) may do the trick here. `kwargs['created'] = True` if we're creating a new object and `kwargs['instance']` is the instance whose save fired off the signal receiver.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Authority)
def update_m2m_relationships(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']: #only fire when creating new objects
        competitors_to_add = Authority.objects.filter(
                                country = kwargs['instance'].country, 
                                category = kwargs['instance'].category
                                )
        for c in competitors_to_add:
            c.competitors.add(kwargs['instance'])
            c.save() #not creating a new object; this receiver does not fire here
            kwargs['instance'].competitors.add(c)
        #all competitors have been added to the instance's m2m field
        kwargs['instance'].save()
```

It's important to only fire this when creating new objects. If you don't include that restriction, then the receiver will trigger itself as you update other objects in your for loop.

I haven't tested this out but I think it'll work. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks.I'm just getting to know about django signals.I looked up on some tutorials on it and I'm confused about where the piece of code should be placed.is it in a signals.py or just a method in models.py or it doesnt matter where?

Comment: Personally, I put my receivers in the relevant `models.py`. Make sure you import `post_save`.

Comment: Are you creating a new object or editing an existing one? If you're creating a new object and it's not working, throw a print statement in the receiver somewhere and watch the `runserver` console while you create another new object. Is the receiver firing?

Comment: I spent some time setting up an app with the same models and constraints, and this signal/receiver pattern appears to work (although I notice now that when you create a new `Authority` it adds itself as a competitor). This is what my setup looks like: http://pastebin.com/Y6Y1LgpL Do you see any glaring differences compared to your environment?

Comment: Please check out this short video https://youtu.be/CVIj_eZCC4k I understand your code perfectly but i can not wrap my head round why it is not working

Comment: You removed the other custom save method stuff, right?  If so, I am not sure what the problem is. The output you're getting in your `runserver` window certainly looks correct. Try opening up a `manage.py` shell, grab that object you just created and look at `something.competitors.all()` manually just to make sure it's empty and not just a display issue in the admin site. While you're in there, try creating a new Authority with `Authority.objects.create(...)` and see if you get the expected functionality there. I'll keep thinking on it but beyond that I'm stumped

Comment: I have done that and it WORKS.It works when creating in shell and the front-end website but doesnt work when when creating in the admin.Its doesnt really matter for me since I need authorities to be created by the users.I can't thank you much for your time.Thank you

Comment: I imagine this has something to do with how `response_add` works in the admin backend, but to be honest I don't use the built-in admin very much so I'm not at all sure. One thing to note is that this current solution will not update competitors properly if you go in and edit an existing authority's category and/or country. You could add an `else` block after the `if kwargs['created']` block with some additional logic if you want to make sure that field stays up-to-date after a model is edited.

Comment: I'll make sure i do that.Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried the 'else' and i replicated the code under 'if' in it,it brings an error 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' when i edit it.Any idea what that means?

Comment: Each save can cause an update on related `competitors`, and those updates can trigger updates, so you can hit recursion depth if there is any kind of loop. A loop in the `else` block might be b/c you're adding `authority` objects to the `competitors` field of an existing `authority` object `A`, but not checking to see if those objects are already in `A.competitors.all()`. You also need to remove relationships where they're no longer appropriate. Try implementing that and posting a new question with what you've tried and the errors you hit, since we're getting outside the scope of your OP.

Comment: Also feel free to link any new question you post here and I will try and help there, too; not trying to run out on you, I just don't want to answer a second separate question in the comments since that's not the "Stack Overflow Way"

Comment: I understand.I will try and brainstorm on it and if i dont get it I'll post a new question

Comment: Hello @souldeux .I have resolved this one on my own completely.Can you help me out on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103632/signals-working-only-in-shell-not-working-in-admin-and-frontend      Thank you