# Signals working only in shell,not working in admin and frontend

Tags: django, shell, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

I am trying to assign some values to a model field after post-save.The model is

```
class Authority(models.Model):
    no_of_feeds=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    no_of_rf=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    no_of_urf=models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Feed(models.Model):
        auth=models.ForeignKey(Authority,blank=False)

    @receiver(post_save, sender = Feed)
    def update_model_feed(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']: #only fire when creating new objects
            kwargs['instance'].auth.no_of_feeds=kwargs['instance'].auth.feed_set.all().count()
            kwargs['instance'].auth.no_of_rf=kwargs['instance'].auth.feed_set.filter(resolved=True).count()
            kwargs['instance'].auth.no_of_urf=kwargs['instance'].auth.feed_set.filter(resolved=False).count()
            print '******************************'
        elif not kwargs['created']:
            kwargs['instance'].auth.no_of_feeds=kwargs['instance'].auth.feed_set.all().count()
            kwargs['instance'].auth.no_of_rf=kwargs['instance'].auth.feed_set.filter(resolved=True).count()
            print '-------------------------------'
            kwargs['instance'].auth.no_of_urf=kwargs['instance'].auth.feed_set.filter(resolved=False).count()
```

As you can see,The signal is used to assign values to `Authority` fields after saving `Feed` model.This works in shell,as the fields are automatically updated but it doesnt work on creating or editing a feed instance in admin or front-end website.Though its print out the '-------' and '****' on execution in the console.Pls kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to do `kwargs['instance'].auth.save()` in order to write those changes to the related `Authority` to the database. If I had to guess, it looks like it's working in the shell because you're looking at the unsaved object in memory, while on your working site you're looking at the values returned from the database.

Comment: That is exactly the cause.It flipped my mind,this is the second time of me using django-signals.Thank you very much

Comment: can you help me answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183479/django-all-auth-form-errors-not-displaying Thanks.