# Django all-auth Form errors not displaying

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth and whenever I input a wrong password in login form,the page just reloads and doesn't show any error.This is my html code:

```
    <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
                        {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
   <span><b> {{error}} </b><span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% csrf_token %}

   <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  {{ form.login }}
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="id_login">Username/Email:</label>
  </div>
   <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  {{ form.password }}
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="id_password">Password</label>
  </div>

  <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="id_remember">
   {{form.remember}}<span class='mdl-checkbox__label 'align='left'>Remember me</span>
  </label></br>
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a><br/></br>
  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button  mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</form>
```

The form displays properly normally and submits normally,if the info input are correct.For sign-up form,the error messages show but it gives a weird one like `'%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.'` if i try to input an email that already exists but for username it gives a normal `A user with that username already exists.`

This is the signup.html

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
    {% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
   <span><b> {{error}} </b><span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  {{ form.username }}
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="id_username">Username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  {{form.email}}
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="id_email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  {{form.password1}}
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="id_password1">Password</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  {{form.password2}}
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="id_password2">Password(again)</label>
  </div>
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
     {% endif %}<br/>

  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button  mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %}</button>
</form>
```

Signup View

```
class SignupView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, CloseableSignupMixin,
                 AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "account/signup." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION
    form_class = SignupForm
    redirect_field_name = "next"
    success_url = None

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SignupView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'signup', self.form_class)

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (
            get_next_redirect_url(
                self.request,
                self.redirect_field_name) or self.success_url)
        return ret

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # By assigning the User to a property on the view, we allow subclasses
        # of SignupView to access the newly created User instance
        self.user = form.save(self.request)
        return complete_signup(self.request, self.user,
                               app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                               self.get_success_url())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(SignupView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = ret['form']
        email = self.request.session.get('account_verified_email')
        if app_settings.SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE:
            email_keys = ['email1', 'email2']
        else:
            email_keys = ['email']
        for email_key in email_keys:
            form.fields[email_key].initial = email
        login_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                                  reverse("account_login"),
                                                  self.redirect_field_name)
        redirect_field_name = self.redirect_field_name
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request,
                                                 redirect_field_name)
        ret.update({"login_url": login_url,
                    "redirect_field_name": redirect_field_name,
                    "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value})
        return ret

signup = SignupView.as_view()
```

Login View

```
class LoginView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin,
                AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin,
                FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "account/login." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION
    success_url = None
    redirect_field_name = "next"

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(LoginView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, 'login', self.form_class)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        try:
            return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)
        except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
            return e.response

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (get_next_redirect_url(
            self.request,
            self.redirect_field_name) or self.success_url)
        return ret

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                                   reverse("account_signup"),
                                                   self.redirect_field_name)
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request,
                                                 self.redirect_field_name)
        site = get_current_site(self.request)

        ret.update({"signup_url": signup_url,
                    "site": site,
                    "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                    "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value})
        return ret

login = LoginView.as_view()
```

Comment: Can you post the view that renders `signup.html`?

Comment: @souldeux The view is not written by me,it comes in the django-allauth package

Comment: @souldeux ive uploaded it already in the question

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have much experience with `django-allauth`. The only thing I can think that might help is checking for `{{form.non_field_errors}}` in your template.

Comment: @souldeux And It is correct.You can post it as an answer,so I can tick it.

Comment: Haha, wonderful, I'll do that now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure to check for `{{form.non_field_errors}}` in addition to errors attached to specific fields.

Answer (score 9):

if any one still having problem then you can use this one

```
{% if form.errors %}
{% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```